# OpenRefine: regex returns null with match() but true with contain()

Tags: openrefine, grel

I'm trying to extract dates from a column of string values in OpenRefine. All dates are formatted with either periods or dashes between values. (e.g. "a_string_12-2-15", "3.12.99_another_string")

I tried `value.contains(/[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+/)` and they all returned true. However, 
`value.match(/[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+/`) returns null. I've also tried replacing [0-9] with \d and that hasn't fixed it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up finding a complicated workaround: `forEach(forEach(value.split("_"),v,v.match(/(\d+[.-]\d+[.-]\d+)/)), i, if(isNotNull(i[0]), i[0], "")).join("")` 
but am still interested in finding a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The [match](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#matchstring-s-regexp-p) function is very counter-intuitive and doesn't work as you think. You can do without it. Since Open Refine 3 there is a [find](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#findstring-s-regexp-p) function that does exactly what you want. :)

So try this instead:

```
value.find(/[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+/).join(',')
```

The `.join(',')` part is just there in case you have several dates in a single string. Otherwise, this is an alternative:

```
value.find(/[0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+/)[0]
```

---

*Just for the record*, you can get the same result with match using this horror (which will not work anyway as you want if you have multiple dates in the same string)

```
value.match(/.*?([0-9]+[.-][0-9]+[.-][0-9]+).*/).join(',')
```